# DevExpress NavBarControl Styles

Tags: winforms, devexpress, navbar, skin

Actually I'm using `DevExpress NavBarControl` to show my menu `Items` and `Groups`.
I have applied `Metropolis Dark` Skin to my Control.
Now my control look like this : [image]

But I want a Layout exactly like `Grid Designer` like `Items` should be `White Color` and `OnHover` of Items should be `Orange` Color like this : [image]

Can anyone help me with this?
is there any thing to do with Glyph Skinning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want a Layout exactly like Grid Designer

As far as I know the `Grid Designer` uses a special skin named the "DevExpress Design" and this skin is not intended to be used anywhere in user code. If you have DX-subscription with source code, you can extract skin-resources from DevExpress sources and load this skin explicitly.
Please, review the [following article about the DevExpress Design skin](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q508189) in this regard.

> is there any thing to do with Glyph Skinning ?

Just use the [NavElement.AllowGlyphSkinning](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraNavBarNavElement_AllowGlyphSkinningtopic) property.
Related help-article: [Glyph Skinning](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument15635).